# SQL Select where NOT matching specific selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been using the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM Events t1
LEFT JOIN UserHistory t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Event
WHERE t2.Event IS NULL
```

To select all rows from table 1 where table 2 is Null. This effectively filters out all my Table 1 data where Table 2 has data. However, I want to apply this only when a column in table 2 equals a certain value. Therefore I am looking to do a `SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.ID = 1` but am unsure how this fits into this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM Events t1
LEFT JOIN UserHistory t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Event and t2.certain_column = 1234
WHERE t2.Event IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try query with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM Events t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserHistory t2 
                          WHERE t1.Name = t2.Event AND t2.ID = 1)
```

Comment: This is true, but [NOT EXISTS does not perform as well as LEFT JOIN/IS NULL in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: @GarethD Missed `MySQL` tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the predicate to the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM Events t1
LEFT JOIN UserHistory t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Event AND t2.ID = 1
WHERE t2.Event IS NULL;
```

If you add it to the `WHERE` you effectively turn your outer join into an inner join, meaning no rows will be returned (since `NULL = 1` evaluates to false)